# Wordpress: Error uploading media "Available temp directory space may be exceeded or the temp file was cleaned up before the upload completed"

Tags: wordpress

I try to upload an image and I get this error. I emptied all the "tmp" folders, included wmufs-temp, on the server and it still shows up. I've also tried creating a new tmp folder and directing it there. But still getting the same error. What I can do?

`There was an error opening the temp file /var/www/html/wp-content/wmufs-temp/1-df8c69043ae11dd7f1af1bd76a7dd2f6c7fafcaa.part for writing. Available temp directory space may be exceeded or the temp file was cleaned up before the upload completed.`

More info: The only change that has happened is that I have pointed a new domain to the page. It was previously in production. The server has not been migrated, the domain has been pointed to it.

I have more than 40 GB free on the server disk and I want to upload a 105 KB image.
The file upload limits are 128 MB set by WordPress and 500 MB set by server.

I have already asked in the Wordpress forum but I have not received an answer, so I check here to see if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact error and I fixed it by disabling all plugins, then I reactivated every plugin one by one. Turns out it was the 'Wp Maximum Upload File Size' plugin. It could be a different plugin in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change permission for folder.

I hope to help you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34769982)